# Why is Parse.com Job: Status = pending and Ended = Not Completed?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a job on Parse.com that runs successfully when I manually trigger it, but when it runs on the schedule I set, it logs: Status = pending and Ended = Not Completed. I'm not passing any parameters to the job.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think here's a related Facebook bug report when jobs were stuck in that state for 5 hours. Facebook eventually resolved that instance of the issue. What you might be seeing may be yet another instance of the same issue. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721251361289141/